# Displaying Google search results in chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to display the item values of a promise in the popup of my browser extension. Currently, the items are the top 10 results from a pre-allocated search. For some context, the aim is for the plugin to find the keywords on a page, google them, find results similar to the page the user is and then display them in the popup. Here is the javascript I have so far:

```
const debiasButton = document.querySelector('#debias-me');
const debiasContent = document.querySelector('#content');
const apiKey = 'x';
const searchEngine = 'x';
const query = 'syria news now';

 debiasButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' + apiKey + 
    '&cx=' + searchEngine + '&q=' + query)
    .then(function(data) {

       const jsonResponse = data.json();
       console.log(jsonResponse);

       for(var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.items.length; i++) {
         console.log(jsonResponse.items.htmlTitle)
       }



   });
});
```

I'm really unsure of how to go about this and whether it may be easier using other libraries or services.

Edit: Sorry for being unclear, the problem is that on the chrome console it shows a promise [] and an error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
If I expand the promise in the console and expand the PromiseValue and go to items it shows Array(10) and lists the results. I don't know how to get them to display in the popup once the button has been clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: So what's the problem? Tip: rightclick the popup and click Inspect to invoke its devtools.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post.

Comment: data.json() returns a promise so you need to "then" it (or await), see any example for `fetch`.

Comment: @John did you ever get chance to finish this extension? Would like to use it.